# mod_rewrite issue with add on domains

Tags: mod-rewrite

I implemented some mod_rewrite rules on my website and they all work perfectly.  However, my web hosting account supports multiple domains on one account by placing the files in subfolders of the directory of my main site.

My mod_rewrite rules seem to interfere with these add on domains.  Does anyone know how I can restrict the rules to just my main domain.  And also could I then add new .htaccess files in the sub folders to have separate rewriting rules for each of the add on domains.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /?error=401
ErrorDocument 403 /?error=403
ErrorDocument 404 /?error=404
ErrorDocument 500 /?error=500

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^\.]+[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?content=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/page/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?content=news&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?content=news&id=$1&ptitle=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photos/page/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?content=photos&page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photos/gallery/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?content=photos&gallery=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^photos/gallery/([0-9]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?content=photos&gallery=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^music/release/([0-9]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?content=music&release=$1&ptitle=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^edit_news/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?content=post_news&id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)?$ media/downloads/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same problem with Bluehost, and it's why I'm now using a virtual private host, such as [prgmr.com](http://prgmr.com)

There was no way around it - so the helpdesk at Bluehost told me. :(